Lasso and cross validation: model selection
Apologies for cross-posting
I am starting to use Lasso and cross validation for model selection to explain a dependent variable using linear models, but I can not understand why all p-values coefficients in selected model are not lower than 0.05:
I use the steps to make this example posted in:
https://www.stata.com/features/overv...on-prediction/
Code:

sysuse auto, clear
splitsample, generate(sample) nsplit(2) rseed(1234)

lasso linear mpg i.foreign i.rep78 headroom weight turn gear_ratio price trunk length displacement if sample == 1, selection(bic)
estimates store bic

lasso linear mpg i.foreign i.rep78 headroom weight turn gear_ratio price trunk length displacement if sample == 1
estimates store cv

lasso linear mpg i.foreign i.rep78 headroom weight turn gear_ratio price trunk length displacement if sample == 1, selection(adaptive)
estimates store adaptive

lassocoef cv bic adaptive, sort(coef, standardized)


----------------------------------------------
             |    cv        bic      adaptive
-------------+--------------------------------
      weight |     x         x    
     5.rep78 |     x         x          x    
      length |     x         x          x    
  gear_ratio |     x                    x    
       price |     x                    x    
       _cons |     x         x          x    
----------------------------------------------
Legend:
  b - base level
  e - empty cell
  o - omitted
  x - estimated




lassogof cv bic adaptive, over(sample) postselection

Postselection coefficients
-------------------------------------------------------------
Name             sample |         MSE    R-squared        Obs
------------------------+------------------------------------
cv                      |
                      1 |    10.92984       0.7046         35
                      2 |    10.77016       0.6496         34
------------------------+------------------------------------
bic                     |
                      1 |    11.82234       0.6805         35
                      2 |     11.0608       0.6401         34
------------------------+------------------------------------
adaptive                |
                      1 |    10.98369       0.7032         35
                      2 |    10.56047       0.6564         34
-------------------------------------------------------------

*adaptive have the lower MSE and higher R^2 in sample 2

*I select adaptative as best model:

. reg mpg length 5.rep78 gear_ratio price

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        69
-------------+----------------------------------   F(4, 64)        =     38.57
       Model |  1654.03213         4  413.508033   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |  686.170766        64  10.7214182   R-squared       =    0.7068
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.6885
       Total |   2340.2029        68  34.4147485   Root MSE        =    3.2744

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      length |  -.1484211   .0270004    -5.50   0.000    -.2023607   -.0944816
     5.rep78 |   3.380391   1.163954     2.90   0.005     1.055125    5.705657
  gear_ratio |   1.558014   1.251733     1.24   0.218    -.9426098    4.058637
       price |  -.0002964   .0001545    -1.92   0.060    -.0006049    .0000122
       _cons |   45.84562   7.960131     5.76   0.000     29.94343    61.74781
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here gear_ratio was selected but its p-value its 0.218, too much high to explain mpg?
I miss some step or concept in model selection using Lasso and cross-validation?
I now that Lasso not use p-value to select the model, but I should remove gear_ratio in the final model?
Any comment I would gratefull
Thanks in advance

A p-value larger than 0.05 never means that a variable should be removed, Lasso or not. Furthermore, standard p-values computed after model selection based on the same data are invalid.

Your statement near the end that you "know Lasso does not use p value" is a key thing. Since you have decided to go with Lasso and cross validation (good for you!) why would you go back to the inferior method of using the p-values?
Unless you made some mistake in your code, you should stick with it.
Of course, you may want to use substantive knowledge or similar things to force certain variables into the model, but I don't know of a reason to force a variable out of the model. If you wanted to absolutely not include a variable, then why even enter it into the equation in the first place?
In any reference on Lasso you will find details of how it works.

Aligned with Peter’s answer, p-values are not good choices for variable selection (you’re not actually doing model selection per se).  But like alost all feature selection methods, lasso is incapable of choosing the “right” features with high probability.  Search for “lasso” in fharrell.com to see examples.  This is why unsupervised learning as a first step (data reduction) is often recommended.

Thanks for your comments, probably I am "contaminated" or more relationated to classic methods for variariable selection (Stepwise). But its normal that after a Lasso cross validation for model selection, get high p-value? I should remove coefficients with p-values > 0.05?

I don't know how normal it is, but you should not remove variables based on p value.

Ok, I get it, thanks for your comments. I will read and will take a decision.
